# Program freezes after connecting to socket and outputting server protocol (Twtich IRC #JAVA)

Tags: java, sockets, irc, twitch

I have this problem that everytime when I press the connect button on my GUI it outputs the server messages and after that my GUI just freezes. I really dont know where the problem is.

ConnectButton (ActionPerformed)

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        try {           
            Connect();   
            ReadMessages();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Something went horribly wrong! (Connect)\n");
        }
```

Connect Method Connect()

```
public void Connect() throws IOException{

this.BotName = jTextField1.getText();
this.AuthKey = jTextField2.getText();
this.Channelname = jTextField3.getText();

this.jTextArea1.append("Starting Connection To: " + Server + "\n");

    try{

    out.write("PASS " + this.AuthKey + "\r\n");
    out.write("NICK " + this.BotName + "\r\n");
    out.write("USER " + this.BotName + " 8 " + this.BotName + "\r\n");
    out.write("CAP REQ :twitch.tv/membership\r\n");
    out.write("CAP REQ :twitch.tv/commands\r\n");
    out.write("JOIN #" + this.Channelname + "\r\n");
    out.flush();

    if(socket.isConnected()){
        this.jButton1.setEnabled(false);
        this.jTextArea1.append("Successfully Connected!\n");
        this.jButton3.setEnabled(true);
    }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Something went horribly wrong! (Connect/func)\n");
    }     

}
```

ReadMessages Method ReadMessages()

```
public void ReadMessages() throws IOException{

            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line); 
            } 

            }
```

Console output before it freezes

```
:tmi.twitch.tv 001 botomig :Welcome, GLHF!
:tmi.twitch.tv 002 botomig :Your host is tmi.twitch.tv
:tmi.twitch.tv 003 botomig :This server is rather new
:tmi.twitch.tv 004 botomig :-
:tmi.twitch.tv 375 botomig :-
:tmi.twitch.tv 372 botomig :You are in a maze of twisty passages, all alike.
:tmi.twitch.tv 376 botomig :>
:tmi.twitch.tv CAP * ACK :twitch.tv/membership
:tmi.twitch.tv CAP * ACK :twitch.tv/commands
:botomig!botomig@botomig.tmi.twitch.tv JOIN #tomig_
:botomig.tmi.twitch.tv 353 botomig = #tomig_ :botomig
:botomig.tmi.twitch.tv 366 botomig #tomig_ :End of /NAMES list
:tmi.twitch.tv USERSTATE #tomig_
:tmi.twitch.tv ROOMSTATE #tomig_
:nightbot!nightbot@nightbot.tmi.twitch.tv JOIN #tomig_
:jtv MODE #tomig_ +o nightbot
```

Comment: `"I really dont know where the problem is"` -- Simply search Google on the terms [Swing program freezes](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+freezes)

Comment: As per the answers to the thousands of similar questions that can be found in the link above: your code does not respect Swing threading, and by running long-running code on the Swing event thread, you prevent the thread from doing its necessary chores such as drawing the GUI and interacting with users. The details of the problem and the solution can be found here: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)